# Spring Ribbon RestTemplate - Mix Eureka and Real URLs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I have a need to mix calls to a [Spring Rest Template](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) using either a Eureka-compliant service name *(example-service-name)* or a real url *(http://my-url.com)*.

The Eureka-friendly URLs work fine, as [Ribbon](https://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.3.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonLoadBalancerClient.html) can look them up without issue. Obviously real URLs fail because they can't be found.

I'd like to be able to integrate Eureka-URLs over time, while maintaining the existing functionality for Spring property-driven direct URLs.

Can I

1. **Configure Ribbon to fall back to a default non-Eureka behavior in the event it fails to resolve a URL ?**

or

2. **Spoof Eureka Name/URL pairs in my local Spring configuration and include them in Ribbon's Eureka url resolution ?**

---

Edit:
Real URLs are failing because the Ribbon client throws an exception if a Eureka lookup fails

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for http://my-url.com
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:75)
```

Comment: why would real url's fail? how are you configuring your routes? can you show that

Comment: Regarding the first point, I have *read* that hystrix (circuit breaker implementation in spring-cloud) can be used to provide fallback when a service fails.

Answer (score 0):

you can regist url as a fake service use this:

```yaml
my-url:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: my-url.com
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
```

and then use `http://my-url/xx/xx`